# How to make style="?attr/actionButtonStyle" workable for rectangle toolbar button

Tags: android

In our previous holo designed app (`targetSdkVersion` 21, with theme `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`), we are using system style attribute **`attr/actionButtonStyle`** to define our custom action bar button style.

### actionbar_custom_view_done_discard.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <include layout="@layout/actionbar_discard_button" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:background="?attr/actionBarCustomViewDividerColor" />    
    <include layout="@layout/actionbar_done_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### actionbar_done_button.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_done"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView style="?attr/actionBarTabTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:drawableLeft="?attr/actionBarDoneIcon"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/save" />
</FrameLayout>
```

### StockAlertFragmentActivity.java

```
public class StockAlertFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Inflate a "Done/Discard" custom action bar view.
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext()
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View customActionBarView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_done_discard, null);
```

The outcome is as following, when we tap on the **SAVE** button.

[image]

However, after migrating our app to material designed app (`targetSdkVersion` 23, theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`), system attribute **`attr/actionButtonStyle`** no longer work well with rectangle button.

Instead, it draws a round overlay on the top of rectangle button.

### toolbar_with_save_discard.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >

    <!-- android:elevation="4dp" is used due to http://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android- -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_discard_button" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:background="?attr/toolbarCustomViewDividerColor" />
        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_save_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

### toolbar_save_button.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_save"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView style="?attr/actionBarTabTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:drawableLeft="?attr/toolbarDoneIcon"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/save" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

I like to have the overlay drawn on the entire rectangle **SAVE** button.

I think most probably I can solve this, by avoiding from using `style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"`, and supplying my very own defined selector.

However, I prefer not to do so. I prefer to use system provided style, for less maintenance headache.

---

***How can I make `style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"` workable for rectangle toolbar button?***

***Or, Is there any other system style attribute, which will work well with rectangle toolbar button? At the same time, having ripple effect.***

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attribute at play here is: `actionButtonStyle` which you set on your wrapping `FrameLayout`. On v23, it points to:

```
<style name="Widget.Material.ActionButton">
    <item name="background">?attr/actionBarItemBackground</item>
    <item name="paddingStart">12dp</item>
    <item name="paddingEnd">12dp</item>
    <item name="minWidth">@dimen/action_button_min_width_material</item>
    <item name="minHeight">@dimen/action_button_min_height_material</item>
    <item name="gravity">center</item>
    <item name="scaleType">center</item>
    <item name="maxLines">2</item>
</style>
```

The `background` is set to `actionBarItemBackground` which in turn points to this `RippleDrawable`:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight"
    android:radius="20dp" />
```

*The radius value is what you don't want.*

To fix this, override `actionBarItemBackground` under your app's theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="....">
    ....
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/custom_action_bar_item_bg</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/custom_action_bar_item_bg</item>
</style>
```

The drawable `custom_action_bar_item_bg` would be defined as:

*res/drawable/custom_action_bar_item_bg.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="#...."/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <color android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

*res/drawable-v21/custom_action_bar_item_bg.xml*

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@id/mask">
        <color android:color="@android:color/white" />
    </item>
</ripple>
```

The `mask` is what will give you the rectangle in case of API version > 21.

---

The downside: all items that use `actionBarItemBackground` will be affected (unless if that's okay). To fix this, you can create a separate theme to set on your `FrameLayout` wrapper. For example, this is your app's main theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="....">
    ....
    ....
</style>
```

Create another theme that inherits from `AppTheme`:

```
<style name="SelectiveActionBarButtonTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/custom_action_bar_item_bg</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/custom_action_bar_item_bg</item>
</style>
```

To use this, override `android:theme` on your wrapper `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_save"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:theme="@style/SelectiveActionBarButtonTheme">

    ....
    ....
</FrameLayout>
```

And of course, the simplest approach would be to set `FrameLayout's` `android:background` to `?attr/selectableItemBackground`, and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks for your lengthy explanation. I'm really appreciated that. I think there is slight typo on the proposed solution. `<item android:id="@id/mask">` should be `<item android:id="@android:id/mask">`

Comment: Instead of using custom drawable, I adopt your last proposed solution - `?attr/selectableItemBackground` - https://gist.github.com/yccheok/0edb860109b8de637b9fb893397ac0fb From my testing, It works pretty good so far. May I know, is there any shortcoming, compared to custom drawable?

Comment: HI Vikram, since I would like to have more control and the highlight color, I try to fall back to your solution by using custom drawable. Your first approach by using `AppTheme` works for me. Since I only would like to retain oval for non-rectangle button too, I tend to add `android:theme="@style/SelectiveActionBarButtonTheme"` on button's `FrameLayout`. But, there's no visual effect after doing so.

Comment: I think the problem is how I use custom theme on button's `FrameLayout`. As, if I use android:theme="@style/AppTheme" on button's `FrameLayout`, the original visual effect (An drawn oval overlay) is not visible too. Any idea on why having `android:theme` on button's `FrameLayout` does work? Thank you.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng We can discuss this here: [Link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111269/how-to-make-styleattr-actionbuttonstyle-workable-for-rectangle-toolbar-button).

Comment: The reason `<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">` does work is that, my app is using light theme black toolbar. `colorControlHighlight` will only work well in light color components. If we change to `<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="#ff0000">`, the ripple effect will be visible to us.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Thank you for the thorough explanation. Really helps to dig into what is actually being set.